# Regex - Remove first 5 and last 4 digits

Tags: .net, regex

We are scanning in a card that needs to have the first 5 numbers removed and last 4 removed.

Example card number (all numbers can can/will change).

> 2011698951650708

So far we have `^.{5}(.{7})` and replacement `$1`

we are getting `98951650708` but want `9895165`

[Link to where I am testing <sup>regexstorm</sup>](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.%7B5%7D(.%7B7%7D)&i=2011698951650708&r=%241)

Using .NET

Answer (score 4):

The regex you're looking for is:

```
\d{5}(\d+)\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
(?<=\d{5})\d(?=\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/XbiMFI/2